# In what cases can I use the expression "standing still"?

Tags: grammar, vocabulary, expressions

I'm wondering which cases can I use the expression "standing still" and which I can't, for example, using "standing still" for abstract concepts like a project, not concrete objects. May you guys provide me some examples and some alternatives to such expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What makes you think you can't use "standing still" in a metaphorical sense? There's no problem with doing so:

> Bob has been out sick for two weeks, so the project has been standing still.

And, from a [2013 news article](http://www.windpowermonthly.com/article/1209699/connection-problems-start-limit-growth):

> The companies that built the wind projects in time, even without a transmission line, were paid strictly according to the contract, ***even if the project was standing still***.

---

If you're looking for an alternate phrase, you can use **in a holding pattern**. That phrase is used to describe [airplanes circling an airport](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/holding-pattern), waiting for their turn to land. However, it is also used metaphorically to describe projects or other work efforts that are making no progress. As a matter of fact, this phrase often creeps into newspaper headlines, such as:

- **Carpenter Park project in a ['holding pattern'](http://www.dailyherald.com/article/20160104/news/160109795/)**
- **City in [holding pattern](http://www.gaffneyledger.com/news/2014-01-13/Front_Page/City_in_holding_pattern_on_Mill_Village_project.html) on Mill Village project**
- **TVCC project in a [holding pattern](http://www.argusobserver.com/news/tvcc-project-in-a-holding-pattern/article_cae44765-bb66-5733-8c0a-9c305d480c2a.html)**
- **Seattle tunnel project in a [holding pattern](http://www.bendbulletin.com/home/2741083-151/seattle-tunnel-project-in-a-holding-pattern)**
- **City in [holding pattern](http://www.wcbcradio.com/?archiv=city-in-holding-pattern-on-what-will-be-done-with-bridges#sthash.Ysr5m3Cv.dpuf) on what will be done with bridges**
- **Mariners GM Jack Zduriencik appears to be in a [holding pattern](http://blogs.seattletimes.com/mariners/2011/12/05/mariners_gm_jack_zduriencik_ap/) on Prince Fielder**

Comment: In the case of inanimates, "at a standstill" sounds slight better to me than "standing still" but that's just a style thing

Answer (score 1):

In the case of a project, you can use 'on hold', e.g.

> The project was put on hold.

Also, closer to your original expression: [to come to a standstill](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/come+to+a+standstill)

> At the height of rush hour, traffic comes to a standstill.

Comment: "it has both real and imaginary parts" - it's exactly what I meant by "concepts like a project, not 3-D stuff", thanks for your neat and explanatory answer